# How to test inner dom function with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a function zoom, and I want to cover `lens.remove()` in my test case. How to write test case for it ?

```
const zoom = () => {
    var lens = document.getElementById( 'lens' )
    lens && lens.remove();
   
 }
```

What I tried so far is

```
 it( 'lens should be deleted ', function(){        
  const remove = jest.fn()
  zoom();
  expect( lens.remove() ).toHaveBeenCalled();
} );
```

But its output is as below

```
    expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has value: undefined
```

Comment: you can do `snapshot` testing or you can check it `document.querySelector('#lens')` returns `null`.

Comment: Well 1. That should be `expect(lens.remove).toHaveBeenCalled()`, you should *pass* the mock instead of *calling* it; and 2. What connection does the `const` in your test function have with `lens.remove`?

Comment: 1. No that not covering  2. const remove = jest.fn() is mock function.

Answer (score 0):

Check element is in DOM,
Call remove method,
Expect that element is not in the DOM.
or
Mock the function,
Expect mock fn has been called.

Comment: Can you please write it ?

Answer (score 0):

So the clue is we need to append lens to dom like this `document.body.appendChild( lens );`